# Spring Environment backed by Typesafe Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, typesafe-config, hocon

I want to use typesafe config (HOCON config files) in my project, which facilitate easy and organized application configuration. Currently I am using normal Java properties file(application.properties) and which is difficult to handle on big project.

My project is a Spring MVC (Not a spring boot project). Is there a way to back my Spring Environment (that I am getting injected to my services) to be backed by typesafe config. Which should not brake my existing Environment usage Like `@Value` annotation, `@Autowired Environment` etc.

How can I do this with minimal effort and changes on my code.

***This is my current solution: Looking for is there any other better way***

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyLoader{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyLoader.class);

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Environment env) {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

        Config conf = ConfigFactory.load();
        conf.resolve();
        TypesafePropertySource propertySource = new TypesafePropertySource("hoconSource", conf);

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = (StandardEnvironment)env;
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        propertySources.addLast(propertySource);
        pspc.setPropertySources(propertySources);

        return pspc;
    }
}

class TypesafePropertySource extends PropertySource<Config>{
    public TypesafePropertySource(String name, Config source) {
        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return this.getSource().getAnyRef(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to add the property source. trying to shoehorn it in like you currently do isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I came up with a slightly more idiomatic way than manually adding the `PropertySource` to the property sources.  Creating a `PropertySourceFactory` and referencing that with `@PropertySource`

First, we have a `TypesafeConfigPropertySource` almost identical to what you have:

```
public class TypesafeConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource<Config> {
    public TypesafeConfigPropertySource(String name, Config source) {
        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String path) {
        if (source.hasPath(path)) {
            return source.getAnyRef(path);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Next, we create a PropertySource **factory** that returns that property source

```
public class TypesafePropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load(resource.getResource().getFilename()).resolve();

        String safeName = name == null ? "typeSafe" : name;
        return new TypesafeConfigPropertySource(safeName, config);
    }

}
```

And finally, in our Configuration file, we can just reference the property source like any other `PropertySource` instead of having to add the PropertySource ourselves:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(factory=TypesafePropertySourceFactory.class, value="someconfig.conf")
public class PropertyLoader {
    // Nothing needed here
}
```

Comment: I needed to add ```    if (path.contains("["))
      return null;
    if (path.contains(":"))
      return null;``` in `getProperty` method to ignore special characters that exist in other PropertySource implementation.

Comment: I special cased the ":" version.  In spring, it provides a default.  So, I split on ":", did a search for the first part, if it doesn't exist, return the second part.

Answer (score 5):

You create a PropertySource class as follows, it is similar to yours with the difference that you have to return the value or null and not let the lib throw a missing exception

```
public class TypesafeConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource<Config> {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(TypesafeConfigPropertySource.class);

    public TypesafeConfigPropertySource(String name, Config source) {
        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        try {
            return source.getAnyRef(name);
        } catch (ConfigException.Missing missing) {
            LOG.trace("Property requested [{}] is not set", name);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Second step is to define a bean as follows

```
    @Bean
    public TypesafeConfigPropertySource provideTypesafeConfigPropertySource(
        ConfigurableEnvironment env) {

        Config conf = ConfigFactory.load().resolve();
        TypesafeConfigPropertySource source = 
                          new TypesafeConfigPropertySource("typeSafe", conf);
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
        sources.addFirst(source); // Choose if you want it first or last
        return source;

    }
```

In cases where you want to autowire properties to other beans you need to use the 
annotation `@DependsOn` to the propertysource bean in order to ensure it is first loaded

Hope it helps

Comment: Even this is right answer , i think the Laplie Anderson answer is more spring way..  But both works;

Comment: I dont think it will work if you return a `ConfigException.Missing`

Answer (score 2):

Laplie Anderson answer with some small improvements:

- throw exception if resource not found
- ignore path that contains `[` and `:` characters

**TypesafePropertySourceFactory.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigParseOptions;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigResolveOptions;

public class TypesafePropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

  @Override
  public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource)
      throws IOException {
    Config config = ConfigFactory
        .load(resource.getResource().getFilename(),
            ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setAllowMissing(false),
            ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem()).resolve();

    String safeName = name == null ? "typeSafe" : name;
    return new TypesafeConfigPropertySource(safeName, config);
  }
}
```

**TypesafeConfigPropertySource**.java

```
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

import com.typesafe.config.Config;

public class TypesafeConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource<Config> {
  public TypesafeConfigPropertySource(String name, Config source) {
    super(name, source);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getProperty(String path) {
    if (path.contains("["))
      return null;
    if (path.contains(":"))
      return null;
    if (source.hasPath(path)) {
      return source.getAnyRef(path);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I advise that the `ConfigResolveOptions.defaults()` be used here in `TypesafePropertySourceFactory` instead of `.noSystem()` as i imagine people may not know why their env variables aren't substituting into their config properly.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above and failed. One particular problem I had was initilization order of the beans. We for example needed flyway support to pick up some overriden properties which come from a typesafe config and also the same for other properties.

As suggested in one of the comments from m-deinum for us the following solutions works, also relying on the input from the other answers. By using an `ApplicationContextInitializer` when loading the main App we make sure that the props are loaded at the start of the App and merged into the "env" correctly:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootConfiguration
@Import({MyAppConfiguration.class})
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class)
            .initializers(new MyAppContextInitializer())
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

The `ContextInitializer` looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class MyAppContextInitializer implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ac) {    
        PropertiesLoader loader = new PropertiesLoader(ac.getEnvironment());
        loader.addConfigToEnv();
    }

}
```

The `PropertiesLoader` works like this to load the properties from the config and stuff it into the environment:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;

class PropertiesLoader {

    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    public PropertiesLoader(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void addConfigToEnv() {
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();

        Config finalConfig = ConfigFactory.load().resolve();
        // you can also do other stuff like: ConfigFactory.parseFile(), use Config.withFallback to merge configs, etc.
        TypesafeConfigPropertySource source = new TypesafeConfigPropertySource("typeSafe", finalConfig);

        sources.addFirst(source);
    }

}
```

And we also need the `TypesafeConfigPropertySource` which works for the typesafe config:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

public class TypesafeConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource<Config> {

    public TypesafeConfigPropertySource(String name, Config source) {
        super(name, source);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String path) {
        if (path.contains("["))
            return null;
        if (path.contains(":"))
            return null;
        if (source.hasPath(path)) {
            return source.getAnyRef(path);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```