# Spring with TypeSafe Config

Tags: java, spring, config, typesafe-config

As of now in my project I load the properties from the property files but instead I want to load it from cassandra. The properties will be stored as a json. I looked at the solution here [Spring Environment backed by Typesafe Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803381/spring-environment-backed-by-typesafe-config) but I still get the exception "com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'spring' ".

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803381/spring-environment-backed-by-typesafe-config

Comment: I answered in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789778/142671 This should fix your issues as well