# spring-boot Environment backed by type-safe config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, typesafe-config

I'm trying to do exactly what @Laplie Anderson suggested here [Spring Environment backed by Typesafe Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803381/spring-environment-backed-by-typesafe-config) but in a spring-boot application.

I want to load different config files for different spring active profiles. Here's an example.

```
@Configuration()
@Import(value = {CommonConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource(factory=TypesafePropertySourceFactory.class, value="config/dev/app.conf")
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {}
```

---

```
@Configuration()
@Import(value = {CommonConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource(factory=TypesafePropertySourceFactory.class, value="config/prod/app.conf")
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfig {}
```

But this results in the following error on app startup..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.buildProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path 'spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties': Token not allowed in path expression: ':' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.PathParser.parsePathExpression(PathParser.java:155) ~[config-1.3.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.PathParser.parsePathExpression(PathParser.java:74) ~[config-1.3.1.jar!/:na]
    ...
```

**What am I missing?**
**Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

The following versions are at play here..
*spring-boot: 1.5.6.RELEASE*
*typesafe config: 1.3.1*

Comment: I am also facing with same problem, did you find anyway to use HOCON configuration along with boot

Comment: I used .yml files instead of HOCON as mentioned in the other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also solve it with the use of a ContextInitializer as I suggested in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789778/142671

Answer (score 0):

For me it works by ignoring the typesafe config unsupported characters.

```java
public class TypesafeConfigPropertySource extends PropertySource<Config> {

  public TypesafeConfigPropertySource(String name, Config source) {
    super(name, source);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getProperty(String name) {
    if (name.contains("["))
      return null;
    if (name.contains(":"))
      return null;
    if (source.hasPath(name)) {
      return source.getAnyRef(name);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

***Notes:***

- It works like a charm with both `Environment.getProperty(property)` and @Value;
- I would expect the `type-safe configuration properties` to work as well. Didn't try yet.

Answer (score -1):

just noticed that spring-boot supports .yml files that have almost all features that I need, esp 'Placeholders in properties'. I'll try to use this instead - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

I'd still like to know the answer to the original question. Is it just because ':' is unacceptable in a typesafe-config value? Is there no workaround?